# Meager Set in Function Space (Constructing Sequence of Functions)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X = \{f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} \; | \; f\in C^1[0,1], f \textrm{ strictly increasing} \}$ equipped with the topology of uniform convergence.  Consider the subset $A =\{ f \in X \; | \; \frac{df}{dx}\Big|_{f^{-1}(1/2)} = 0\}$.

I'm trying to determine whether or not $A$ is meagre in $X$ (a set is meagre if it is an at most countable union of nowhere-dense sets, i.e. sets such that the interior of their closure is empty).

To do this, I am trying to show that any $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $f \in \bar{A}$ is not contained in $\bar{A}$.  Clearly for any $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of a function $f \in A$ there is a strictly increasing function $g\in X$ whose derivative is nowhere zero and such that $g^{-1}(1/2)=f^{-1}(1/2)$. For such a function, $g \not \in A$ but is in an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $f \in A$.

However, it is not clear to me that such a function is not in $\bar{A}$.  Ultimately, this is a question of 'can I approximate a function that has strictly positive derivative everywhere on some interval with ones that have derivative zero on at least one point'.

My intuition is that for fixed $f$, on a small enough ball around $f^{-1}(1/2)$ the derivative of $g$ being strictly positive bounds $f$ away from $g$ in the sup norm.  But it is not clear to me that as a sequence I can't pick $f$'s that 'slope up sufficiently quickly after $f^{-1}(1/2)$ enough to make up for that.

I'm not quite sure what the best way to proceed on this latter point is.  Any advice on that topic is greatly appreciated; alternatively, if there is some other way of looking at the larger problem, any advice is equally appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be the identity function. Given $f \in X, \varepsilon > 0$, the open set $\{f + \delta h : \delta \in (\varepsilon/2, \varepsilon)\}$ is contained in the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $f$ and is disjoint with $A$. So $A$ is nowhere dense in $X$.

Comment: That's a very nice proof. I was hung up trying to do it for arbitrary $g$ with everywhere positive derivative.  I ended up having to assume second derivatives exist, and a bit of other stuff to do it and rely on Arzela-Ascoli.  Very clean, thanks.

Comment: I've thought about this a bit- at first blush it I took it for granted that $\{f+\delta h : \delta \in (\varepsilon/2 , \varepsilon)\}$ was open but now I'm not so sure.  How would you suggest proving that? Surely I can find functions outside of that set converging to it? Say $f$ is linear, then so is  every element of $\{f+\delta h : \delta \in (\varepsilon/2 , \varepsilon)\}$, thus can't I find a sequence of functions outside the set converging into it?